# Changing projection on each page of data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, data-driven-pages, utm

I am working with data driven pages and a raster image of the world. I have a separate polygon shapefile of all of the UTM zones (with a polygon for zones 1-60, north and south, for a total of 120 polygons).

I have added a field to the polygon shapefile where I defined the Well-Known ID (WKID) of each feature (each zone, eg, 1N, 2S, etc). These WKID's are based on the WGS 1984 UTM zones, north and south (eg 32731). I set this field to be a "short integer" per this article: http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40411

In the data-driven pages settings I have set the "Spatial Reference" to this WKID field.

However, when I make the data driven pages, the projections don't change from page to page, and are all still rectangles (because my coordinate system for the data frame is just set to the basic WGS 1984). I'm expecting them to use this WKID to change the projection to the WGS 1984 UTM projections for each zone, so that each page of the data driven pages shows the correct projection for that zone.

Can you think of anything I'm missing to accomplish this?

Comment: When I did this in my "[Map Books made easy using Data Driven Pages](http://discoverspatial.com/courses/data-driven-pages)" eLearning video tutorial I used the Calculate UTM Zone tool to write full spatial references into a field rather than just WKIDs, and that seemed to work fine.

Comment: I was able to get the tool to work, but it won't add UTM zones to all of my features, just about a fourth of them?

Comment: It's interesting that you say that because in my course transcript I wrote "I initially planned to do this for all the World Cities but I was finding that only the European Cities were being centred correctly so I reduced my dataset to use just them instead.  I think there may currently be a bug that enables Data Driven Pages to only work properly with the UTM Zones within one quadrant of the world at a time but I have not yet worked through this with Esri."

Comment: Hmm, that is what it seems to be doing! When I saved my edits it shortened the values down quite a bit to things like 

PROJCS["GCS WGS 1984 UTM Zone 01G (Calculated)",GE

I was hoping to have them use the WGS 1984 north and south, and not be based on the more specific sub-zones that the G implies...

I wonder if I just edit them to, say Zone 01N if that would work, and repeat the process for all the values. Trying now...

Comment: Hmm, this time when I ran the tool it actually gave me errors saying it's skipping features because of null or empty geometry?

Comment: Yeah, it's just totally not working. Even with the UTM zones that were successfully input with this tool, it doesn't change the projection.